# Use Resources from Nearest server out of 2 Shared Servers I have

Tags: load-balancing, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I don't know where and whom to ask this question, but serverfault seems to be a good platform where experts can answer.

I  have 2 shared server accounts at different companies (both servers are placed in separate countries - US and India).

What I am thinking is, whenever any visitor lands on my website, he should get the data from the nearest server. If user/visitor is from India, he should see website data loaded from India server and similarly visitors from US will see data fetched from US server.

Can I do something which can manage this?

Also please note both the servers are shared space from the hosting provider. I know there are lot of limitations on Shared-Hosting accounts.

What I can think in direction is, creating a load-balancer at AWS and use both the servers. But don't know whether this is feasible or not.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is to use a CDN. Even free services provide this functionality.

For example if you use cloudflare your content will be delivered from their [Global Anycast Network](https://www.cloudflare.com/network/). [Anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) means that your content would be served to your visitors from cloudflare's topologically nearest node to them.

That being said you don't even need two servers from your side. CDN will fetch your content from your server and will cache it in their nodes.

To be honest i am not 100% sure that this is a free cloudflare service. I searched a lot in their site and they don't state neither if its free or if its paid so l guess that it is free.

Finally there are a lot of CDN providers out there. I am not related to Cloudflare in any way. I didn't wanted to advertise neither of them. I just mention them as an example after kasperd's comment.

Comment: If you gave examples of how to configure it on a couple of those free solutions, this could be a good answer.

Comment: I edited my initial answer and mentioned cloudflare. In their control panel you just follow a wizard. No special configuration is needed.

Comment: But I don't wan't to use CDN, I just want my 2 shared-hosts to provide data basis latency. And that too on the all content, whether dynamic content or static. CDN is only for the static content serving.

Comment: @Lynda A proper CDN can tell the difference between static and dynamic content such that only static content is cached. If you insist on having users connect directly to the closest of your servers, then you'll need to host your DNS zone on a CDN.